# convert php variable to javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I've tried to convert a php-variable like this (in Javascript):

```
var kaartkeuze = "<?php echo json_encode($kaart1); ?>";
```

This gives a result in Chrome/console:

`kaartkeuze :<?php echo json_encode($kaart1); ?>`

So, I suppose there is something wrong with (magic) quotes?
Has anybody suggestions?

Comment: Make sure `$kaart1` actually has  a value

Comment: What is the value of `$kaart1`?

Comment: Make sure that the extension is .php or you have enabled php in HTML files, otherwise the code will not run.

Comment: You seem to serve the file directly instead of passing it through the PHP interpretor.

Comment: Of course, there is always the chance that `$kaart1` contains a string  value of '<?php echo json_encode($kaart1); ?>' ... ;)

Comment: I am 100% sure that your file is not `.php` file  that is why PHP code is not running and is printed as it is

Comment: Just checked it: $kaart has a value.

Comment: So, I need to rename my .html file to a .php file?

Comment: What is very unclear is where the relevent line of code resides: In a PHP program or in a JS script?

Comment: Is everyone missing that JS will not executed PHP code? This is just a string assigned to a JS variable.

Comment: @BigScar the php code will be parsed before the page is rendered on the browser. See my answer for more details!

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP to write the JS code... 
For example, in your HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Title of your page
</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
<?php
     $kaart1 = "your variable value";
     $json = json_encode($kaart1);
     echo "var kaartkeuze = ".$json.";";
?>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the point here is actually he is not parsing php code so what is the goal of doing this?

Comment: Hi, I didn't get your point... Do you mean that my code isn't parsing php code?

Comment: OP's error is that his php code is parsed as plain text. So you don't really provide a solution with a solution fully based on php, do you agree? ;) anyway your solution is technically right.

Comment: Got it, but the question isn't about parsing PHP code, instead, the question is  to convert PHP variable value on JS variable value.Furthermore, thinking logically, there is no way to client(in this case JS) change the server state. The most probable is server(php) change the client state(JS).

Comment: I alway thought that it was not possible to combine Javascript and php in file?

Comment: Yeah, it is possible, but, the only way to do it is changing the client side(JS) from server side(PHP).

Comment: Php files can have js inside. You need to focus on the difference between server side (php) and client side (js). What you cannot do is running is trying to add some php to a page once it has been rendered on browser. If you need to do that (for example to fetch new data from a db) you need to use Ajax that is designed for that.

Comment: @Lelio: thanks for the explanation. I think I need an Ajax solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct to say you convert a php variable in a js one. When the browser read the file and execute js part of it your php has already been parsed by php engine (server side).
So the server will transform this:

```
<?php echo json_encode($kaart1); ?>
```

in an array encoded like:

```
{"balance":1000.21,"num":100,"nickname":null,"is_vip":true,"name":"foo"}
```

so when it will come to the browser to read it your line of code will look:

```
var kaartkeuze = {"balance":1000.21,"num":100,"nickname":null,"is_vip":true,"name":"foo"}
```

you are getting your error for two reasons:

- your file extension is different from php;
- you have not configured php to be parsed on your server so php code
  (including  tags will be just treated as plain text.

**EDIT: looking at the last comments please rename .html to .php or your server will never know it has to parse your file using php interpreter**

Comment: If I rename my file, the PHP-code is activated, but the Javascript code doesn't work any more, so I don't understand how this should work.

Comment: Conserning your second bullit: how do I have to configure my php code on the server?

Comment: What do you mean your js is not executed? Can you post the whole code? It is really strange!!